# How to add eventListener at dynamic elements?

Tags: javascript

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var add = document.getElementById('addButton');
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.deleteButton');

    add.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        table.innerHTML += `<div class="row">
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                                <span class="deleteButton"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </div>`;
    });

    deleteBtn.forEach(function(btn) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log(this);
        })
    })

});
```

```css
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.table-wrapper {
    /* width: 90vw;
    max-width: 900px;
    min-height: 80px; */
    width: 600px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #e6edf0;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.table-wrapper>.row {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ecf1f4
}

.table-wrapper>.row.header {
    background-color: #ecf1f4;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #b0b0b0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.table-wrapper>.row>span {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
}

.table-wrapper>.row>span:nth-child(1) {
    width: 40px;
}

.table-wrapper>.row>span:nth-child(2) {
    width: 80px;
}

.table-wrapper>.row>span:nth-child(3) {
    width: 60px;
}

.table-wrapper>.row>span:nth-child(4) {
    width: 60px;
}

.table-wrapper>.row>span:nth-child(5) {
    width: 80px;
}

.table-wrapper>.row>span:nth-child(6) {
    width: 40px;
    color: #c0c0c0;
}

.table-wrapper input[type=text],
.table-wrapper select {
    height: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

i.fa-trash {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.btn-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #e6edf0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous>



<div class="wrapper">
        <div id="table" class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="row header">
                <span class="">idx</span>
                <span class="">name</span>
                <span class="">type</span>
                <span class="">options</span>
                <span class="">output</span>
                <span class=""> </span>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <span class="">1</span>
                <span class=""><input type="text" /></span>
                <span class=""><select><option>Name</option></select></span>
                <span class=""><select><option>Korean</option><option>English + Korean</option></select></span>
                <span class="">Kim</span>
                <span class="deleteButton"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="addButton" class="btn-wrapper">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> ADD ROW
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to develop with `vanila JS`.

And I'm making a table it is having `add` function and `delete` function.

I made `add` function successfully, but I can't make `delete` function about dynamic elements.

When I clicked **ADD ROW** button, one row is added to the table.

And I clicked **delete icon**, I want to see `console.log(this)`.

But, it's not working.

Have you ever any idea to solve this with `vanilla JS`?

I know it is simple problem, so I want to say that I'm sorry and Thank you so much.

**Summary**

How can I add `eventListener` at dynamic elements efficiently?

Comment: add an event listener to the parent element.

Comment: I made a very simple example for you. Feel free to make changes in that code and it should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What am I trying to do?

let say I want a list. I can add more element by clicking a button and if I click on a list item the title of the list should change.

The first approach is what you are doing in your code. The 2nd approach is what you should do to fix it.

## Approach #1 - That won't work

You can find the reason below the code snippet why it won't work.

```js
var title = document.getElementById("title"),
    parent = document.getElementById("parent"),
    child = document.querySelectorAll(".child"),
    add = document.getElementById("add");
    
add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  parent.innerHTML += '<li class="child">New element</li>';
});

child.forEach(function (child) {
  child.addEventListener("click", function() {
    title.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
  });
});
```

```html
<h3 id="title">This is a title</h3>

<ul id="parent">
  <li class="child">First element</li>
  <li class="child">Second element</li>
  <li class="child">Third element</li>
  <li class="child">Fourth element</li>
</ul>

<button id="add">Add element</button>
```

This is known as **Event delegation**. When the page was first loaded the dynamically generated LI where not in the DOM and the click event was not attached to them. So try the code below which can solve that issue.

## Approach #2 - That should work

```js
var title = document.getElementById("title"),
    parent = document.getElementById("parent"),
    child = document.querySelectorAll(".child"),
    add = document.getElementById("add"),
    counter = 1;
    
add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  parent.innerHTML += '<li class="child">New element ' + counter + '</li>';
  counter++;
});

parent.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if ( e.target.nodeName == "LI" ) {
    title.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
  }
});
```

```html
<h3 id="title">This is a title</h3>

<ul id="parent">
  <li class="child">First element</li>
  <li class="child">Second element</li>
  <li class="child">Third element</li>
  <li class="child">Fourth element</li>
</ul>

<button id="add">Add element</button>
```

Hope this example helps to understand **event delegation**. If any issue drops a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Use Event Delegation which is a procedure of leveraging event bubbling and the event object Event.target (commonly the element clicked, changed, hovered, etc.). The most efficient way to employ event delegation using plain JavaScript is to add an event listener to an ancestor element that all targeted elements have in common (it can be `parentElement` (mom), `parentElement.parentElement` (grandma), ..., even `document` or `window`).

**Details commented in demo and [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/U9uMqu436X0276uO2GnZ/)**

**References located after demo**

### Demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    body {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .table-wrapper {
      /* width: 90vw;
    max-width: 900px;
    min-height: 80px; */
      width: 600px;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid #e6edf0;
      max-height: 400px;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    
    .table-wrapper>.row {
      height: 40px;
      width: 100%;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ecf1f4
    }
    
    .table-wrapper>.row.header {
      background-color: #ecf1f4;
      font-weight: lighter;
      color: #b0b0b0;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .table-wrapper>.row>span {
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 12px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .table-wrapper>.row>span:nth-child(1) {
      width: 40px;
    }
    
    .table-wrapper>.row>span:nth-child(2) {
      width: 80px;
    }
    
    .table-wrapper>.row>span:nth-child(3) {
      width: 60px;
    }
    
    .table-wrapper>.row>span:nth-child(4) {
      width: 60px;
    }
    
    .table-wrapper>.row>span:nth-child(5) {
      width: 80px;
    }
    
    .table-wrapper>.row>span:nth-child(6) {
      width: 40px;
      color: #c0c0c0;
    }
    
    .table-wrapper input[type=text],
    .table-wrapper select {
      height: 30px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      max-width: 50px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    i.fa-trash {
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    .btn-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: white;
      margin-top: 15px;
      border: 1px solid #e6edf0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      line-height: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 13px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>




  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="table" class="table-wrapper">
      <div class="row headed">
        <span class=" ">idx</span>
        <span class=" ">name</span>
        <span class=" ">type</span>
        <span class=" ">options</span>
        <span class=" ">output</span>
        <span class=" "> </span>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <span class=" ">1</span>
        <span class=" "><input type="text" /></span>
        <span class=" "><select><option>Name</option></select></span>
        <span class=" "><select><option>Korean</option><option>English + Korean</option></select></span>
        <span class=" ">Kim</span>
        <span class="btn deleteButton"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="addButton" class="btn btn-primary .btn-wrapper">
      <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> ADD ROW
    </div>
  </div>





  <script>
    var add = document.getElementById('addButton');
    var table = document.getElementById('table');


    add.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

      /* insertAdjacentHTML() is like innerHTML on steroids
      || See references for details
      */
      table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="row">
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                                <span class="btn deleteButton">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>`);
    });

    /* Register table to click event...
    == if e.target (the element clicked i.e. .fa-trash) 
    || is NOT e.currentTarget 
    || (the element registered to event i.e. #table)...
    == if e.target has the class .fa-trash... 
    == Get the grandparent of e.target (i.e. .row)
    == Remove the .row
    */
    table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('fa-trash')) {
          var row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
          table.removeChild(row);
        }
        /* Prevent the event bubbling to keep
        || any unwanted elements from being 
        || triggered
        */
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
    }, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### References

[**Event Delegation**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

[**insertAdjacentHTML()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

[**Event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

[**Event.currentTarget**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)