# Textarea doesn't detect value change with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I am using javascript to update textarea value with alt of an image when that image is clicked and immediately send it.

```
var chatInput = document.querySelector(selector);// Text area selector
var chatSend= document.querySelector(selector); // Send button

parent.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName == 'IMG'){
        var imageName = e.target.alt;
        chatInput.value = imageName;
        chatSend.click();
    }
})
```

If I use .innerHTML the value appears inside of textarea inner html but doesn't appear in textarea value and i can't send it.

If I use .value the value appears inside of textarea but doesn't appear in innerHTML and i still cant send it unless i add at least one letter or a space typed by me. That's of course after i disable chatSend.click()

Is there a way to make textarea think that the message was typed by a user?

Note: it's irrelevant whether value appears or not as long as it's being sent.

Comment: You code is very poor! Don't add event listeners in a for loop instead add event listener on the parent element.. look at this  for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/47853498/5519872

Comment: @RaajNadar Hey thanks for that suggestion. My bad it's just that i have been taught to do it this way. I will adjust it right now.

Comment: If you find that code useful make sure you upvote the question & answer! Probably that code will resolve your issue as well

Comment: I can't upvote yet but I would if I could. Sadly this is not the solution. Do you have any idea how could i possibly simulate a 'spacebar' keypress in textarea to make it look like user pressed it himself? @RaajNadar

Comment: please add a fiddler or live demo so that I can check what is going wrong!

Comment: @oban_internet Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem right now.

Comment: @FlorianWalther Check my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75430383/3356446

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code :

```
var chatInput = document.getElementById("chatInput").value;
```

Sample Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/syaiful007/xpvt214o/86302/

Comment: No that's not it. I already have the value, I just need to paste it into text area as if user wrote it himself because text area doesn't detect it otherwise. So maybe i should create an event that simulates 'spacebar' keypress?

Comment: Maybe sample is you have 2 textarea... And then textarea 1 keypress textarea 2 worth textarea 1 ? Is that true?

Comment: No, that's not it either. Text area is properly selected. The text just doesn't get updated when i put it into value or innerHTML.

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this one out? I'm struggling with the same issue.